# How to simplify this content upload form?

Tags: website-design, usability, forms

[image]

There are several options, all of which are necessary, but it's very intimidating and kinda unwieldy -- especially for nontechnical users. A similar form is used to type in plain text.

Comment: This looks like a good case for a wizard.

Comment: Looks good enough to un-hold.

Comment: @z-boss - Nope, still looks like a "Site Review" question, which is the exact reason it was put on hold.

Comment: @CharlesBoyung Well, the problem he's trying to solve is creation of a simple interface for uploading different kind of information (files and text) from different sources (local PC and the Web).  
It might look like "site review" because he's showing his solution to the problem.  
Is there any way this question can fit the rules?

Answer (score 2):

No suggestions about the form per se, all the options seem to be fine. A more spacious layout would possibly bring a bit clarity to the form.

You might want to conduct a usability test to the site/form with a handful of actual end users to see what are the most critical problems.

As a bonus, below are a few findings in general.

- the cancellation of the text/file selection is too hidden

  - the 1st phase of the process could be link to the initial state
- after the share is created, there is no explicit link or URL to share (although the 3rd step so suggests)
- when hovering the info tooltips, cursor changes to indicate an action, but nothing happens when clicking
- when downloading, the site only shows the original file "as is", instead offering it as a direct download

  - set `Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=[file.ext]")`
- clicking the "Search for a post" link automatically uses "infotomb" as search criteria and the search field is too detached from the results

  - bring the search field directly above the result listing

Answer (score 1):

The user basically has three courses of actions, correct? Show three buttons that lead to separate forms **or** have all three options in the same form but all disabled by default.

- **A. Upload file** [`file` input]
- **B. Paste URL** [`text` input]
- **C. Type text** [`textarea`]

Your current layout is initially confusing. Pasting a URL into a text field and typing text into a field are not uploading in the traditional sense, so labelling them as "Upload" is misleading.